# Getting day of the week not working when using setNumberFormat

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like programably enter the date into a cell and format it to include the Day of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed,...).    If I use the .setNumberFormat method (which I would prefer to do because it keeps the info as a date), the simpleDateFormat for Day of the week does not work.   If I use Utilities.formatDate I can use 'EEE, MM/dd' and it will show up correctly, but I lose the date format.

```
function setformat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lab = ss.getSheetByName("test2");

  // This is what I want to use but the day of the week 'EEE' doesn't work
  var todaySNF = new Date();
  lab.getRange("a1").setValue(todaySNF);
  lab.getRange("a1").setNumberFormat('EEE, MM/dd');   // Should read Wed, 09/23 but reads EEE, 09/23 instead.
  var cellA1asDate = new Date(lab.getRange("a1").getValue());
  Logger.log(cellA1asDate);}
```

Comment: september 23 2014 is tuesday ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead :

```
  lab.getRange("a1").setNumberFormat('DDD, MM/dd');
```

[image]